# Typo3 10 TCA "'type' => 'inline'," create new relation and upload button auto hide

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

After upload and save 1 relation/file, the "create new relation" and "select and upload" button is not showing. Due to that issue, I am unable to update that attached file or edit the record.

Below are the TCA configuration code for that field:

```
'catalogs' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'catalogs',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'catalog',
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'expandSingle' => 1,
                'newRecordLinkAddTitle' => 0,
            ],
            'foreign_field' => 'supplier',
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 5,
        ]
    ],
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug introduced with TYPO3 v10.4.11 and fixed in 10.4.13:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/93091

Please update your TYPO3 to the latest version.